# Node.js error when using jsrsasign.jws.JWS.sign - undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm using jsrsasign to sign an identity token.  I'm getting the following error:

> Error: init failed:TypeError: undefined is not a function

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var fs = require('fs')
var jsrsasign = require('jsrsasign');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

  //create header, claim, and read privateKey from a file    
  .....

  var jws = null;
  try {
    jws = jsrsasign.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", header, claim, privateKey);
  } catch(e) {
    return res.status(500).send('Could not create signature. Error: ' + e + '\n Header: ' + header + '\n Claim: ' + claim + "\n PrivateKey: \n" + privateKey);
  }
```

The variable - header, claim and privateKey - all have a value. The jsrsasign.jws.JWS.sign is the part that fails.

I would appreciate any help in figuring out what this error means.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

I changed the way I was reading private key from a file.

```
privateKey = fs.readFileSync('keys/layer-key.js');
```

to

```
privateKey = fs.readFileSync('keys/layer-key.js').toString();
```